# Wordpress install within another wordpress website (permalinks issue)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a "/new" directory on an existing Wordpress install and the site itself works though going to any other page will return a 404 from the old website. ie:

- website.com -> old website, works
- website.com/new -> new website, works
- website.com/new/about -> displays 404 from old website

I've re-saved the permalinks settings in an attempt to make sure the htaccess file was correct, is there maybe a way in the old websites .htaccess file that I can ignore anything in the /new directory from it attempting to try and find a page in the old website?

Comment: HAve you tried re-saving your permalink settings in the admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an htaccess file in the `/new/` directory that does the appropriate routing. If there is no routing, then simply have:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

to essentially turn off all mod_rewrite activity when going into the `/new/` directory.

Comment: This seemed to do it, editing my /new htaccess file prefixing any of the paths with /new did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following rule to your roots .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^(new)($|/) - [L]
```

Before the line that says:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

That should stop solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the .htaccess in the root directory (/) and make sure the .htaccess in the /new directory has [the correct permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#.htaccess_permissions) so that Wordpress can modify it.

Comment: Eek! Delete the .htaccess in the root? What about main Wordpress install in the root?